ELSS NAV bought which were not shown as investment in ITR Can be redeemed before three year?
I invested in bandhan elss fund in 2022 and claimed in ITR, next year I again invest in same fund as it had good return but I did not claim it in ITR deduction as I opted for new tax regime and it was profitable for me that time.
Now can I sell the nav which I bought in 2023 before maturity ?
Issues here -

Maturity of fund is three year but that's only applicable when you are claiming income tax deduction on it, otherwise it's just a regular fund and you can redeem it at any time subjective to exit load.

As redemption follows fifo rules these can be treated as nav bought in 2022 and as they are not yet matured I might subject to income taxes.

Is there any advantage keeping this fund so that I can claim it in next year ITR assuming I might shift to old regime.



An ELSS or equity-linked savings scheme is a tax-saving investment option under Section 80C of the Income Tax Act, 1961.The lock-in period for ELSS investments is 3 years. This means that once you invest in an ELSS scheme, you cannot redeem or withdraw your investment for a minimum of 3 years from the date of investment.
You can sell the investments only after the lock-in period of 3 years ends. Even if you try to sell before the lock in period, Bandhan Mutual Fund will reject your request .
Answers to your issues

After the completion of the lock-in period, you have the freedom to redeem the units partially or in full.
No the NAV brought in 2022, can be sold only in 2025 ie from 3 years after date of purchase
Every financial year you have to make an investment in ELSS where you can claim tax exemption of maximum Rs. 1.5 Lakhs

